# Hyperlink in Maximo start center?

Tags: hyperlink, configuration, maximo, ticket-system

[image]

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

Is it possible to put a custom hyperlink or button in the start centre?

Ideally, the hyperlink or button would be in a custom container/box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes.

Export LIBRARY.xml, modify it by adding a full URL, then re-import it:
[Creating a hyperlink on the start center](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/creating-hyperlink-start-center)

Additional information here: [Add URL to Maximo Start Center](https://interprosoft.com/maximotimes/maximo/premium/add-url-to-maximo-start-center/)